# tabula only reads first two rows

Tags: pandas, pdf, web-scraping, tabula

I am trying to scrape a table from a online pdf, but the indexing is not working properly.

see table[0] and table[1]

What i want is a DataFrame with strings in all columns, so i can extract the ICD codes with regex.

```
import tabula
import pandas as pd
file = "https://www.bmj.com/content/bmj/suppl/2015/02/03/bmj.h246.DC1/junm020747.ww1_default.pdf"
table = tabula.read_pdf(file1,pages=[1,2,3],multiple_tables=True, guess=False)
table[0] # only part of first row in table
table[1] # all seperate rows of random rows in pdf
```

What i am looking for is to get a dataframe with the text organized as the pdf looks like.
col1: e.g. Intracranial, col2: string, col:3 string